# Laravel View - Edit Page getting the select form with option trigger value to open input field

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.4 and i have a select form with an option value that triggers input field

**My View:**

```
<select name="event_type" id="event_type">
   <option value="" disabled>Choose Event</option>
   <option value="Kids Party" {{ old('event_type',$client->eventDetail->event_type) == "Kids Party" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Kids Party</option>
   <option value="Debut" {{ old('event_type',$client->eventDetail->event_type) == "Debut" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Debut</option>
   <option value="other">Specify</option>
</select>

<div class="input-field col s12 event_type_other">
   <input name="event_type" type="text" placeholder="Specify.." value="{{ $client->eventDetail->event_type }}" class="validate">
   <label for="event_type">Make your own selection!</label>
</div>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    var $select2 = $('#event_type');

    $select2.formSelect();
    $select2.on('change', function (e) {

        if($(this).val()==="other"){
            $('.event_type_other').show();
        }else{
            $('.event_type_other').hide();
}
}).change();
});
```

My question is how can i get the **option value = other** to be **selected** if the value from the database is not equal to the value of Kids Party and Debut

I tried to do this but it won't work

```
<option value="other" {{ old('event_type',$client->eventDetail->event_type) != "Kids Party" ? '' : old('event_type',$client->eventDetail->event_type) != "Debut" ? '' : 'selected' }}>Specify</option>
```

I am open for other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement like this

```
<select name="event_type" id="event_type" onchange="myFun()">
   <option value="" disabled>Choose Event</option>
   <option value="Kids Party" {{ old('event_type',$client->eventDetail- 
   >event_type) == "Kids Party" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Kids Party</option>
   <option value="Debut" {{ old('event_type',$client->eventDetail->event_type) 
   == "Debut" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Debut</option>
   <option value="other">Specify</option>
</select>

<div class="input-field col s12 event_type_other" id="myDiv" @if (@$client->eventDetail->event_type!= "others") style="display: none; @endif>
   <input name="event_type" type="text" placeholder="Specify.." value="{{ 
   $client->eventDetail->event_type }}" class="validate">
   <label for="event_type">Make your own selection!</label>
</div>
```

And in your script

```
<script>
   function myFun() {
      var value = $('#event_type').val();
      if(value == "other") {
         $('#myDiv').show();
      } else {
         $('#myDiv').hide();
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: when i load the edit page and for example the value is "Wedding" the select form is not getting the specify option because the value is not other. In my understanding this code will only work if the value from the database is "other"
I am thinking maybe i need to have a reference that the option value is "other" then getting the value of "other" => "Wedding" if that makes sense.

Comment: I edit the answer. If any other type will come then the div is hidden. Check the condition in that div like the answer

Answer (score 0):

I just added this in my controller

```
        $event_type = Client::findOrFail($id);

        if ($event_type->eventDetail->event_type !== "Kids Party" AND $event_type->eventDetail->event_type != "Debut")
        {
            $new_event_type = "other";
        }
        else
        {
            $new_event_type = " ";
        }
```

And this for my view

```
<option value="other" {{ old('event_type',$new_event_type) == 'other' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Specify</option>
```

It's working now for me